# wp-comments-post.php file returns a blank page

Tags: php, functions, comments, headers, server

When i post a reply to my blog, it's return a blank page to me.

It seems that happens because of this code in wp-comments-post.php

```
if ( 'POST' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
    header('Allow: POST');
    header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    exit;
}
```

I hosted the same blog with the same content in other hosting and it works fine, so i guess there should be a misconfiguration in the hosting server.

Does anyone has the same issue so can help me out with?

Comment: So what is happening - are you posting to that URL and having it rejected by the PHP, or is your browser not actually POSTing? You could try tracing out `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` in the error if you're not sure (e.g. put it at the end of the `HTTP/1.1 405` line), or use your browser debug tools to see exactly what request it's sending to the server. Do you know what web server your new host is using?

Comment: @Rup It's rejected by the PHP, and the web server is nginx, I'm using WPENGINE and they offer staging area, the site is working fine in the staging area but have this issue in the live site.

Comment: Please talk to their support people then if you haven't already - chances are they'll have seen this before and will know what to do. My best guess if that the `REQUEST_METHOD` is being set differently by nginx then, e.g. 'post' lower case?, but I don't know.

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy like Varnish?